# How to prevent factorial from being evalauted?

Tags: algebra

Suppose I have:

```
Do[Print[i/i!], {i, 1, 10}]
```

I would like the output to be like:

> 1/1!, 2/2!, 3/3! , ...,10/10!

However, when I use the code above the factorial evaluates by Mathematica. I tried to enclose the factorial part by `TraditionalForm` or `Unevaluated` but it didn't help.

How can I get the form I like as above?

Comment: There are many similar questions. Search for `HoldForm`: `#/HoldForm[#!] & /@ Range[10]`

Comment: It seems inside a loop `HoldForm` doesn't work.

Comment: Use `With` to inject `i`. Or `Inactivate[Factorial][i]` or `#/HoldForm[#!] &[i]` inside the loop.;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizing the suggestion of @Kuba `With`:)

Like this:

```
Do[
 Print[
   With[{j = i}, HoldForm[j/j!]]], {i, 1, 10}]
```

Or

```
Table[
  With[{j = i}, HoldForm[j/j!]], {i, 1, 10}]
```

> $\left\{\frac{1}{1!},\frac{2}{2!},\frac{3}{3!},\frac{4}{4!},\frac{5}{5!},\frac{6}{6!},\frac{7}{7!},\frac{8}{8!},\frac{9}{9!},\frac{10}{10!}\right\}$